# Calling a function in another component based on the condition, whether the tab is active or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Example 1:

click on tab1. Tab 1 is active tab. Click again on tab1(tab1 is active tab) I don't want to call function  start() in component 'Details'. Click on tab 2 or tab 3 I want to call function start() in another component 'Details'.

Example 2:

click on `tab2`. Tab 2 is active tab. Click again on tab2(tab 2 is active tab) I don't want to call function start() in component 'Details'. Click on tab 1 or tab 3 I want to call function `start()` in another components 'Details'.

Tries to create a condition in the 'Details' component. If the tab is not active, call the `start ()` function. Move the function `isActive ()` and the variable `selectedTabId` from the component 'Tabs' to 'Details' and call the start function there if the tab is not active. Is my reasoning correct? Is this a good approach?

Code here: https://codepen.io/kaka-milan/pen/oKXJma?editors=1111

Drawing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuzYl.jpg

**Tabs**

```
var Tabs = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { selectedTabId: 1 }
  },

  isActive: function (id) {
    return this.state.selectedTabId === id;
  },

  setActiveTab: function (selectedTabId) {
      this.setState({ selectedTabId });
  },

  render: function() {
    var total = this.props.data.points.total,
        tabs = total.map(function (el, i) {
          return <Tab 
            key={ i }
            content={ el.name } 
            id={el.id}
            isActive={ this.isActive(el.id) } 
            onActiveTab={ this.setActiveTab.bind(this, el.id) }
          />
        }, this);

    return 
    <div>
      <ul className="navigation">
       { tabs }
      </ul>
      <Details 
        isActive={ this.isActive}
        selectedTabId={this.state.selectedTabId}
      />
    </div>
  }
});
```

**Details**

```
var Details = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount() {
     if(!this.props.isActive(this.props.selectedTabId)){
      this.start();
    }
  },

  start: function() {
    return console.log('aaa')
  },

  render: function() {
    return 

      <p></p>

  }
});
```

Comment: Instead of `componentDidMount` you need to use `componentDidUpdate` in `Details` component - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the problem is that `Details` is rendered when `Tabs` is rendered so `start` is only called on first render. Also `Details` has no way of knowing when state is changed.

One solution is to move `start` into `Tabs` and call it in `setActiveTab` if needed, like below. This allows us to remove the `Details` component altogether:

```
var Tabs = React.createClass({
  ...
  setActiveTab: function (selectedTabId) {
      if(selectedTabId !== 
      this.setState({ selectedTabId });
  },
  start: function () {
      console.log('aaa')
  },

  ...
})
```

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/sentaipadas/pen/JgYPmq

I haven't worked with react classes for a while, but if you have access to React 16.8 and want to separate state handling logic from rendering (it looks like that is the aim of `Details` component) you can use React hooks (with classes you could possibly use `ref`s).

Example codepen: https://codepen.io/sentaipadas/pen/mNeboE